# Fundamental representations and weight space dimension

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For the Lie algebra $\frak{sl}_n$, its fundamental representations can be realised as the exterior powers of the first fundamental representation. From this we can see that their weight spaces are all $1$-dimensional. Is this true for the other series - are the weight spaces of the fundamental representations always $1$-dimensional. If this is true, does it identify the fundamental representations, that is are the fundaental representation precisely those with $1$-dimensional weight spaces?

Comment: Some unpubllished notes from 2014 and 2016 are on my webpage, with further bibliographic references: http://people.math.umass.edu/~jeh/pub/fund.pdf.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ and denote the fundamental highest weights by $\varpi_1, \ldots, \varpi_l$, where $l$ is the rank of $\mathfrak{g}$ and the ordering of the $\varpi_i$ is the usual one (Bourbaki).

The cases where an irreducible representation of highest weight $\lambda$ has all weight spaces $1$-dimensional are the following:

- Type $A_l$: $\lambda = \varpi_i, c \varpi_1$, or $c\varpi_l$.
- Type $B_l$ ($l \geq 2$): $\lambda = \varpi_1$ or $\varpi_l$.
- Type $C_l$ ($l \geq 3$): $\lambda = \varpi_1$. For type $C_3$, also $\lambda = \varpi_3$.
- Type $D_l$ ($l \geq 4$): $\lambda = \varpi_1$, $\varpi_{l-1}$ or $\varpi_{l}$.
- Type $G_2$: $\lambda = \varpi_1$.
- Type $E_6$: $\lambda = \varpi_1$ or $\varpi_6$.
- Type $E_7$: $\lambda = \varpi_7$.

So most fundamental representations do not have $1$-dimensional weight spaces. Also, in type $A$ you have non-fundamental representations which have all weight spaces $1$-dimensional. These can be realized as symmetric powers of the natural irreducible representation and its dual.

For a reference, see Chapter 6 in Seitz, *The maximal subgroups of classical algebraic groups* (Memoirs of the AMS). Seitz works with algebraic groups, but this will of course give you the result for Lie algebras as well.

Seitz actually proves a result over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p \geq 0$. In characteristic $p > 0$ we get some additional examples, such as $\lambda = d \varpi_i + (p-d-1) \varpi_{i+1}$ in type $A_l$ (for $1 \leq i < l$ and $0 \leq d < p$).

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that outside types A and C, the adjoint representation is fundamental, but the $0$ weight space (i.e. a Cartan subalgebra) is not one-dimensional.

Comment: Here is more detail on the AMS Memoir by Gary Seitz:  https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=888704

Answer (score 1):

Such representations are actually quite rare and are superset of the [minuscule representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minuscule_representation).

Comment: Thanks for the terminology. I have also heard people talk about cominiscule representations . . . I guess these are related?

Comment: For type $B$, the natural representation has all weight spaces of dimension $1$, but it is not minuscule. Another example would be irreducible of highest weight $\varpi_3$ for type $C_3$.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen Oops. Thanks for spotting that mistake.

Comment: @PierreDubois Sorry, I don't really know much about these. If you happen to find some nice reference, please let me know.