# Weight space dimension of the fundamental representation $\pi_n$ for type $C_n$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Will the fundamental representation $\pi_n$ of type $C_n$, for $n > 3$, have weight spaces of dimension greater than $1$? Is there some online resource where weight space multiplicities can be calculated? If so this would make $C_n$ the only non-exceptional type for which the first and last Dynkin node did not give an irrep with one-dimensional weight spaces. Is there any conceptual explanation for this?

Comment: I think the answer is yes, some weight space will have dimension $> 1$, unless you are taking about groups of type $C_n$ in characteristic two. See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314597/fundamental-representations-and-weight-space-dimension/). Frank Lübeck's website might also be useful: [link](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Frank.Luebeck/chev/WMSmall/index.html).

Comment: @Mikko: In the book you referenced in the linked question, it seems the author claims that C_n has $1$-dim weight spaces, for all $n$. Is this an error, or am I reading the notation incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LiE software does these calculations, and is available on line:

http://wwwmathlabo.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/form.html

Comment: I don't see an explicit weight space function. How can one deduce this from the given functions?

Comment: Choose Full character from the pulldown menu for multiplicities of all weights, or Character multiplicities for just the multiplicities of the dominant weights.