# Character formula for the fundamental representations of $\frak{sl}_n$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For the Lie algebra $\frak{sl}_{n+1}$ we denote its fundamental irreducible representations by $V(\pi_i)$, with $i=1, \dots, n$. Where can I find a table of the character formula (in other words a list of all the non-zero weight spaces of $V(\pi_i)$ together with multiplicities)?

P.S. From this answer

[Fundamental representations and weight space dimension](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314597/fundamental-representations-and-weight-space-dimension)

it looks that the multiplicities are also 1. So my question simplifies to a table of the non-zero weight spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are examples of so called *minuscule* weights which are defined through the property that all the weights are given by $w\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the highest weight and $w$ is an element of the Weyl group. So, in the $\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}$, to get all the weights in "the $\epsilon$ basis" you just take all possible permutations of coordinates of $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I could use a little more detail. Does Weyl conjugate just mean the action of an element of the Weyl group on a weight? When you say take all permutations, what is it that you are permuting?

Comment: @MartimPereir Sorry, conjugated is perhaps not the right word to use here. I've edited the answer to make it more clear. Please don't hesitate to ask further questions.

Comment: The weight lattice of $\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}$ is $\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}/\mathbb{Z}(1,1,\ldots,1)$ and $\pi_i = (1,1,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ (with $i$ $1$'s). The nonzero weights in $V^{\pi_i}$ are then, as the answerer says, the permutations of $\pi_i$, i.e., all $1$/$0$ vectors with $i$ $1$'s. They all have multiplicity one.